# How to know what packages I'm missing?

Tags: rpm, distributions, suse, zypper

A while ago I made my own distro of Linux using `SuseStudio` and may have left out some important packages.

- Apps like `gnome-software` and `gnome-music` don't work
- The computer runs really high process rates, doing simple tasks like `web browsing`
- `vmware` can't recognize hardware acceleration
- Overall sluggishness about the machine is existent

In the past I would update to the latest package version, but now I feel that I'm missing some packages.

Is there a `zypper` command I can run or a way to install all the base SuSe rpms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running `zypper` in the verification mode:

```
zypper verify -D
```

That should report any inconsistencies in package dependencies. See the `zypper(8)` man page.